# Looking for a weather API that does historical forecast data

Tags: weather, weather-api

I am looking for a very specific type of historical weather data.

Is there a weather API that can give me a history of forecasts that where done in the past. For example if I were to request data for some day I could then access forecasts for the next x days given on the specified day. Ideally x would be maybe 3 days to a week.

So basically I would be able to see the forecasts as if I was currently in 6/5/15 maybe as far as the next weekend.

As far as I can tell most weather APIs will give historical actual weather data, that is they will tell me what the weather actually was on a specified day, that is also reflected in most of the questions here on stack overflow but is not what I am looking for.

Is anyone aware of a service like this?

Comment: why the downvotes? I have looked for this too and it is hard to find.

Comment: a quik google search showed me lots of relevant API's https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+api+historical+forecast&oq=weather+api+historical+forecast&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.7212j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

you can try this http://openweathermap.org/history

> Through our API we provide hourly historical weather data for cities and historical data from weather stations. Find more about historical data availability in price-list.

there are options to call the api via city name, lat long, etc.

examples of API call:

```
http://history.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?id={id}&type=hour&start={start}&end={end}

http://history.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?id={id}&type=hour&start={start}&cnt={cnt}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:
https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/api/

Their historical API provides historical weather forecasts (instead of historical weather data).
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> The ESRL/PSD 2nd-generation Reforecast Project has produced a dataset of historical weather forecasts

https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/forecasts/reforecast2/

You'll need to read the documentation to understand what is available and how to parse it.

https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/forecasts/reforecast2/README.GEFS_Reforecast2.pdf